# How can I display a record from my MySQL database using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm unable to display a particular record in PHP. This is my code:

```
<?php

session_start();
$name = $_SESSION['MM_Username'];
mysql_connect("localhost","abc","sar");
mysql_select_db("abc");
$query = mysql_query("select * from employee WHERE username = '$name'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($query));
{ 
  echo $row['employee_id'];
}   

?>
```

This does not display anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: try `print_r($row);` to see what is in that variable

Comment: So where is your error handling? [mysql_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php)

Comment: You're mixing up mysql_fetch_row, which gives you a numerically indexed array of results; with mysql_fetch_array, which gives you an associative array.

Answer (score 6):

You are using `mysql_fetch_row` which returns numerical array.  You should be using `mysql_fetch_assoc`, for eg.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{ 
  echo $row['employee_id'];
}
```

Please read through the documentation of both:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

Note: Also please don't ignore the warning.  Start using either PDO or mysqli.

Comment: I did that..even used mysqli..but still no progress..did the error handeling too ut it ain't showing any error

Comment: Is that semicolon in `while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query));` intentional?  You won't see syntax errors with that semicolon but the while block does not execute with that semicolon.  Please remove it and give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Did you even debug your work? Does $_SESSION['MM_Username']; contain anything? Try print_r($_SESSION); to make sure.

You can also echo just your query and test it directly on your Database to make sure there any expected results showing up.

If you did this and it still is not working: please provide more information.

Comment: I've already checked this...the print_r($_SESSION) is giving the correct username and group

Comment: As I said; add additional info because we can't see what your expected results are (from the Database), what the current information in MM_Username is. It could possibly go wrong on so many levels now: Your MySQL statement might be invalid because you're not escaping a special character, the MySQL field might be case sensitive which you forgot to take into account, I don't know. Give us some data to work with.

Comment: @BjornSchijff, no additional info is necessary. See vinodadhikary's answer.

Comment: @Mischa Of course, if he had debugged the results he had gotten (or checked the number of results), he could have figured this out himself. Debugging is key.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();
$name=$_SESSION['MM_Username'];
mysql_connect("localhost","abc","sar");
mysql_select_db("abc");
$query = "select * from employee WHERE username =  '$name';";
$result = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());    
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
{ 
echo $row['employee_id'];
}   
?>
```

or something like that

Answer (score 0):

First enable error reporting :

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

Then follow code below :

```
<?php
session_start();
$name = $_SESSION['MM_Username'];

mysql_connect("localhost","abc","sar") or die("No Connection"); //Add or die() to record any error if connection is failed
mysql_select_db("abc") or die("can't select");

$query = mysql_query("select * from `employee` WHERE username = '".$name."'") or die("Wrong query"); //makesure table name with backtick eg: `tablename`

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query));  //also can use : mysql_fetch_assoc($query)
{ 
  echo $row['employee_id']; //print output
}   
?>
```

1. Enable error reporting
2. Add `or die()` to check if failed
3. Always use backtick for table name . Why? check [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html)
4. Try use `mysql_fetch_array($query)` or  `mysql_fetch_assoc($query)`
5. And please don't use `mysql_*` in future. Why ? check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: did all that..still no result...the page is still blank

Comment: try to view page source.. also try clear browser cache if you can.. and restart xampp(if you use xampp)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)** but please use **mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)** because mysql_ is deprecated.

And in future if you have some problem with your code please call funcion **var_dump()** for debugging reasons, or you can set xdebug in your php.ini file and connected with your environment tool (like NetBeans or something similar).

If you are interested in NetBeans and xdebug you can visit this [link](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/debugging.html).